# send specific data from shown table (PHP)

Tags: php

I have complicated problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx5IL.jpg)

In this image I created php page to get the data from mysql database
and every message have id in database
If I click on image of check mark we will go to another page to answer the message

I get the id already from the DB

```
"SELECT msgId.....
```

and store it in var from the next array

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ..............
            $msgIdVar = $row['msgId'];
```

and the check mark image is input form

```
<input type="image" src="img/chckMrk.jpg" alt="Submit Form" name="msgIdVar" value=""/>
```

when I try to pass the $row['msgId'] as a $_POST var, it didn't working with me!

```
<input type="image" src="img/chckMrk.jpg" alt="Submit Form" name="msgIdVar" value="' . <?php echo $msgIdVar; ?> . '"/>
```

also this doesn't work:

```
.....value="' . <?php echo $row['msgId']; ?> . '"/>
```

The problem here:

I want if we click the second message for example, send the id for this message to another page

How can i do it???

Comment: You appear to be mixing two different syntax's right here: `value="' . <?php echo $row['msgId']; ?> . '"` ... If you are using echo on this entire line, just do `value="'.$row['msgId'].'"` ... Else if you are writing the HTML outside of PHP scope, use `value="<?php echo $row['msgId']; ?>"`

Comment: @GaryThomas 
You are right :)
because I'm in PHP scopre, I just use
    value=" ' . $msgIdVar . ' "
and it work, THANK YOU for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an `<input type="image">` to send data using a form. Use an `<input type="hidden">`, and use your image as the trigger to submit the form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="msgIdVar" value="<?php echo $msgIdVar ?>" />
    <input type="image" src="img/chckMrk.jpg" alt="Submit Form" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Guillaume
your code working with me :)
But, because we still inside PHP scope, I use

    value=" ' . $msgIdVar . ' "

Thank you for your help